# Is $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-t)^k B^{k-l-1}}{k!}$ summable in a closed form

Tags: summation

I am wondering if $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^k B^{k-l-1}}{k!}$$ is sumable in a closed form. We have $t\in \mathbb R$, $l\in \mathbb N$. For $B$ I am interested in two cases: $B\in \mathbb R$ and $B$ is a square matrix over the field of real numbers.

Edit
The same question for the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-t)^{k+l+1} B^k}{(k+l+1)!}$$?

Comment: Is $$B^{-l-1}\cdot e^{-tB}$$ a closed form to you? (notice that you need $\det B\ne 0$ ).

Answer (score 2):

One can write your series as
$$\frac{1}{B^{\ell+1}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\left(-tB\right)^k}{k!}$$
which equals to
$$\frac{e^{-tB}}{B^{\ell+1}}$$
This holds when $B$ is a scalar or an invertible matrix (assuming you are familiar with the concept of exponent of a matrix).

Comment: yes, thanks, I made a mistake typing the wrong sum, which is trivial. I added another one that I am actually interested in.